# PHP - pass an extra parameter (variable) to set_exception_handler

Tags: php, variables, exception, callback, closures

Is there any way to pass variable to the set_exception_handler() method in PHP? I need something like this:

```
class Clazz {

    public /* static */ function foo() {
        set_exception_handler(array('Clazz', 'callback'), $var); // I need to pass $var

         // or this in non-static context
         $that = $this;
         set_exception_handler(array($that, 'callback'), $var); // I need to pass $var
    }

    public static function callback($exception, $var) {
        // process $exception using $var
    }
}
```

Comment: why dont you extend the Exception class to one you can get those vars out? like `new myException(...,...,$var)` and then in the handler `$e->getVar()`

Comment: I call some libraries in foo() method. The code in them throws exceptions and I can't change it. Neither redefine exceptions nor avoid them at all.

Comment: what about using a lambda-function?

Comment: Yes, I need something like that. But how can I use it? I haven't found any option in manual pages to do that with set_exception_handler.

Comment: Could the title be changed to something more representative of the actual question? It's fairly misleading.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I did change the title so it fits the topic better. However, you can generally edit questions on your own, or suggest an edit, with your reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As i already indicated in the comment you have to use lambda-functions anyway:

```
 $lambda = function($exception) use ($var) {
    Clazz::callback($exception,$var);
 }

 set_exception_handler($lambda);
```

Comment: And how can I pass real value of $var to the callback when calling set_exception_handler? There is no such option.

Comment: can you specify this? by doing `use ($var)` the $var is given into the function. this means it will be fix in your lambdaFunction

Answer (score 2):

Use a callback

```
set_exception_handler(function($exception) use($var){
    $that->callback($exception, $var);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to catch the exception and re-throw a derived one which has this custom property.

```
class MyLibraryException extends LibraryException {
    function __construct(LibraryException $e, $custom_field){
         $this->custom_field = $custom_field;
         ...
    }
}

try {
    ...
} catch(LibraryException $e) {
    new MyLibraryException($e, $cusotm_field);
}
```

Comment: hm, i guess thats what he doesnt want to do, cause i already commented him to do that

Comment: he says he cannot change the code in the library but what i suggest doesn't require such a change. so i guess this might be useful to him ...

Comment: This is useful if I'd know all kinds of Exceptions in the library. It would work after all, but I'd like to have something more elegant, if possible. However, thanks for your solution. Also thank @androidavid, he suggested something similar above.